# wordpress add featured image below post title

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to display a featured image below the blog-post title. 
actually my posts look like:

```
WP-header
post-title
date | author | comments
post content
tag | category
```

My goal is to get a full-sized-image (featured image) between `post-title` & `date | author | comments` 
Actually I am using a Corpo Theme.

Any ideas?
Best Regards

Comment: Are you inserting your image as featured image or inserting image inside post content?

Comment: @MonirulIslam only as a featured image

Comment: Ok. I have added answer. Please check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch featured image using following code and paste it after `post-title` which should be `<?php the_title() ?>`

```
<?php 
 if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
   echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
   the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
   echo '</a>';
 }
 ?>
```

Since i haven't seen your full code so i can help you up-to this.

See [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) Tutorial

Comment: but one more little thing: I want the image at full width - similar to a slider. What do I have to change?

Comment: If you want to get your full width image then use $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full'); instead of $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');